# VBA - Adding several rows with one button

Tags: excel, vba, button

Dear Stackoverflow community,
I would like to add several rows that display values from cells in other sheets with one CommandButton. I have the code for adding one row but I don’t know how to extend it to adding several rows at once.

As a little side information: the Excel document is a housekeeping book. I want to add 14 rows with each 8 columns for different categories of expenses (row 1: sumarry values for the year, row 2-13: individual values fort he 12 months, row 14: empty row). All the values for row 1-13 are in a separate sheet for the respective year.

Here is my code for adding one row (in German, sorry!, at the moment showing the summary values for the respective year:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
i = 1
Zeile = Worksheets("Übersicht").Range("A4:A5000").End(xlDown).Row
Zeile = Zeile + 1
Jahr = InputBox("Neues Jahr eingeben (zB: 2017)", "Neues Jahr")

Sheets("Vorlage").Copy After:=Sheets(1)
Sheets("Vorlage (2)").Name = Jahr
Sheets("Übersicht").Select

For i = 1 To 5
     If i = 1 Then
     Range(Cells(Zeile, 1), Cells(Zeile, 2)).Select
     GoTo Weiter
     End If
     If i = 2 Then
     Range(Cells(Zeile, 3), Cells(Zeile, 4)).Select
     GoTo Weiter
     End If
     If i = 3 Then
     Range(Cells(Zeile, 5), Cells(Zeile, 6)).Select
     GoTo Weiter
     End If
     If i = 4 Then
     Range(Cells(Zeile, 6), Cells(Zeile, 7)).Select
     GoTo Weiter
     End If
     If i = 5 Then
     Range(Cells(Zeile, 7), Cells(Zeile, 8)).Select
     GoTo Weiter
     End If

Next i
Cells(Zeile, 1).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(Zeile, 1), Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        "'" & Jahr & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:=Jahr
Cells(Zeile, 1).Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
Cells(Zeile, 2) = ""
Cells(Zeile, 3).Formula = "='" & Jahr & "'!A6"
Cells(Zeile, 4).Formula = "='" & Jahr & "'!B6"
Cells(Zeile, 5).Formula = "='" & Jahr & "'!C6"
Cells(Zeile, 6).Formula = "='" & Jahr & "'!D6"
Cells(Zeile, 7).Formula = "='" & Jahr & "'!E6"
Cells(Zeile, 8).Formula = "='" & Jahr & "'!F6"
End Sub
```

Thanking you in advance,
Selina

Comment: What is the code at `Weiter`? You could use `Resize` to insert multiple rows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How can I use the "resize" property in this respect? Could you give me a code example? I only know "resize" in the context of making a number of rows and columns larger or smaller. How can I use to insert several rows with specific data given in a different sheet? Thanking you in advance

Comment: For example, `range("A1").Resize(3).EntireRow.Insert` will insert 3 rows.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it :)